# What is the correct date format for parsing dates in Jackson?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I'm mapping a Map to a Java model, everything was working fine until today. It seems to be failing with some new data. Here's the error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of   
java.util.Date from String value '2013-08-14T12:16:02.31-05:00': not a valid
representation (error: Can not parse date "2013-08-14T12:16:02.31-05:00": not
compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-
MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

In my Jackson ObjectMapper bean I have set the date format:

```
<property name="myFormat">
    <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"/>     
    </bean>
</property>
```

What is wrong with the date format?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one digit from milliseconds; otherwise that would match the default ISO-8601 value. So if possible, just produce date/time values that use 3 digits, not 2.

In addition, your custom date format may not be registered via Spring (not sure, I don't use Spring myself); but if it is, you are specifying that literal `Z` is to be used for timezone; but your value actually uses relative offset. So you will probably need to leave quotes out.